# PrintWriter using a StandardCharset

Tags: java

If I were to create an `InputStreamReader` with the following code,

```
new InputStreamReader(anInputStream, "UTF-8")
```

I would have to catch `UnsupportedEncodingException`, which is reasonable. I can avoid this by using

```
new InputStreamReader(anInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

which doesn't throw `UnsupportedEncodingException` as the charset is already known to be valid. All good so far.

Now enter its counterpart, the PrintWriter:

```
new PrintWriter("filename", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

doesn't compile because the PrintWriter constructor doesn't take a Charset argument. I can do this:

```
new PrintWriter("filename", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())
```

but then I can't avoid having to catch `UnsupportedEncodingException`, even though the charset name has just come from a valid charset.

The `StandardCharsets` utility class was added later on in Java's lifetime, and when Sun added it, they also added an overload to the `InputStreamReader` constructor. Why did they add an overload to `InputStreamReader` but not `PrintWriter`?

Is there another class I can use instead, which takes a charset instead of a charset name?

Comment: `java.io.OutputStreamWriter` ?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers. The problem was insufficient coffee.

Comment: I know how you feel, Klitos...A programmers life: `while(me.isDead()==false){timeElapsed++; experience++; caffeine.decrease(); while(caffeine.getPercentage()<100){coffee.drinkMore();}}`  =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counterpart to `InputStreamReader` is not `PrintWriter`.

Use `OutputStreamWriter` instead.

If you want to use `PrintWriter`, it's possible to use `PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(anOutputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Answer (score 3):

The counterpart of `java.io.InputStreamReader` is `java.io.OutputStreamWriter`, not `java.io.PrintWriter`.

That said, you can create the `PrintWriter` safely like this:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(anyOutputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(anyInputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
```

Answer (score 2):

> but then I can't avoid having to catch UnsupportedEncodingException, even though the charset name has just come from a valid charset.

Which makes sense, right? Since it's still a String.

As suggested by Stewart, using the java.io.OutputStreamWriter would be the way to go.

```
new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(anOutputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), isAutoFlush)
```